# Array of dates want to be use in paramater ( year calendar bootstrap) (customDayRenderer)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, iteration

So i have an option named customDayRenderer

```
var redDateTime = new Date(currentYear, 2, 13).getTime(); 

$('#calendar').calendar({ 
        customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
            if(date.getTime() == redDateTime) {
                $(element).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                $(element).css('font-size', '15px');
                $(element).css('color', 'green');
            }
            else if(date.getTime() == circleDateTime) {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
                $(element).css('color', 'white');
                $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
            }
            else if(date.getTime() == borderDateTime) {
                $(element).css('border', '2px solid blue');
            }
        }
    });
```

as i have many dates that i want to change the css, i made an array.

```
var weekendDate = [new Date (2018, 1-1,6).getTime(),new Date (2018, 1-1,7).getTime()];
```

how do i iterate the array of dates to change the css?

Comment: "as i have many dates that i want to change the css" , is it particularly an array of dates of weekends?

Comment: yes correct as the bootstrap year calendar doenst have any css style to manuall color the weekend, i have to use the customDayRenderer, i want to color all the weekend from this year until the next 5 years for etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can do something like this:

```
var weekendDate = [new Date (2018, 1-1,6).getTime(),new Date (2018, 1-1,7).getTime()];

$('#calendar').calendar({ 
        customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
            if (weekendDate.includes(date.getTime())) {
               // Do your custom css here
            }
        }
    });
```

But, there is a better way of doing, given you want some custom css for Weekends.

You don't need to construct the array of weekends, the `customDayRenderer` will be called everytime the library about to render 'day'. So you can just check if the 'day' is weekend or not:

```
$('#calendar').calendar({ 
            customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
                if (date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0) { // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
                   // Do your custom css here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tqsm anasceym, it works like i wanted. really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I'm having problem where the color from the data source cannot replace the color of the custom day renderer.

Comment: I do not get your problem, can you update with example code and more explanation